# Self contained ruby "binary"?

Tags: ruby, linux

[Ruby Noob]

I have a small (command line) utility written in Ruby, which `require`s a few gems. Is there a way to create a self contained bundle of my program such that I can run it on another machine that has Ruby installed (but not necessarily the gems)?

FWIW, the target machine runs Linux/Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the gem bundle http://gembundler.com/
With bundle you create a Gemfile in your project root - a text that contains all your dependencies, very similar to Maven concept

In order to fetch all your dependencies simply tun

```
bundle install
```

The only issue is that you need to have the bundle gem itself installed, so you are back with the chicken-or-Egg problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've used:

http://www.erikveen.dds.nl/rubyscript2exe/

before, but it was a while ago.  Seemed to work okay for simple programs.

You can download it here:

http://rubyforge.org/projects/rubyscript2exe/